# List the variables in higher scopes

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I'm trying to write a function that will list all the variables within my current python session. To my understanding I can use the 'dir()' and 'locals()' function to do this. However, when I call these from a function, they only show the variables within the scope of that function. How can I list the variables in the main function from within another function?

Comment: Are you looking for `globals()`?

Comment: tried globals() but it doesn't work. I think because I declare the function from within another file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the built-in `globals()` function: 
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals

Comment: I tried the globals() function but that doesn't seem to work.